# lubridate changes year when date is incomplete

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to organize a VERY messy data.frame and I find `lubridate` to be a life-saver overall, but I just noticed a funny thing in a few of my rows.

Mostly, when the date string is incomplete, such as `NA/NA/1971`, `lubridate::mdy()` satisfactorily declares the whole thing `NA`, and I'm fine with that. But in a very few lines, it has a different idea: `mdy("8/NA/1965")` gives me a Date object `8/19/2065`. Clearly, this isn't what I was hoping for, but I cant figure out why it does that.

When I try writing the same thing in the console, it works fine, but when applying `mdy` to the whole `data.frame`, the above happens, always in the same few lines.

Comment: Suggest you report it to the maintainer of the package and just use `as.Date("8/NA/1965", "%m/%d/%Y")` instead.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  `mdy("8/NA/1965")` returns me NA and a warning.